# SharePoint Online REST API delete multiple items in single request

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

My scenario is, I have a list called ChildList with parent item ID. 
In the child list, I have multiple items with parent ID. Now I want to delete multiple child items passing single ParentID. Like we do in SQL, "Delete from table where columnname=value". This will delete multiple rows having same column value. Can this be done REST API using JSOM/CSOM ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**REST API**
Note:  Expecting that `PARENTLIST` '*ID*' field is a lookup field in `CHILDLIST` with name '*PARENT*'

Call the `DeleteChildItems` function by passing the *parentId*

```
function DeleteChildItems(parentId)
{
    getItems("/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('CHILDLIST')/items?$filter=PARENT/ID eq "+parentId).done(function(data){
        var noChildItems = data.d.results.length; //number of child items to be deleted
        data.d.results.forEach(function(item){
            var childId = item.ID;
            deleteItem("/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('CHILDLIST')/getItemById("+childId+")",item).done(function(d_data){
                //deleted child item.
            });
        });
    });
}



//Get items
function getItems(url){
    return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        }
    });
}

//Delete Item
function deleteItem(url, oldItem) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
        type: "DELETE",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "If-Match": oldItem.__metadata.etag
        }
    });
}
```